# Dataframe with datetime64 dtype insert into to postgressql timestamp column

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am taking a dataframe and inserting it into a Postgresql table.

One column in the dataframe is a datetime64 dtype.  The column type in PostgreSQL is 'timestamp without time zone.'  To prepare the dataframe to insert, I am using to_records:

```
listdf = df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
```

When I run the to_records, it gives an error at the psycopg2's cur.executemany() that I am trying to insert Biginit into a Timestamp without timezone.

So I tried to add a dict of column_dtypes to the to_records.  But that doesn't work. The below gives the error: "ValueError: Cannot convert from specific units to generic units in NumPy datetimes or timedeltas"

```
DictofDTypes = dict.fromkeys(SQLdfColHAedings,'float')
DictofDTypes['Date_Time'] = 'datetime64'
listdf = df.to_records(index=False,column_dtypes=DictofDTypes).tolist()
```

I have also tried type of str, int, and float.  None worked in the above three lines.

How do I convert the column properly to be able to insert the column into a timestamp sql column?

Answer (score 2):

I removed defining the dtypes from to_records.
And before to_recordes, I converted the datetime to str with:
`df['Date_Time'] = df['Date_Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`
The sql insert command then worked.